# List Style not being applied to Ajax Jquery List

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I've been trying to dynamically create an unordered list from XML to a JQuery mobile page.
I can get the items to show up on the page, but the style never appears as it should..with the normal blue link plain text, that is all. Is there another method of styling the list?

```
<ul id="events-holder" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "event_list.php",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('event').each(function() {
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var date = $(this).find('date').text();
                var url = $(this).find('url').text();

                $('<li></li>')
                    .html('<li><a href="'+url+ '" rel="external" data-transition="slide">'+ title +'</a></li>')
                    .appendTo('#events-holder')
                    .trigger('create'); 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Issue with the styling..]

Comment: What is the CSS you are applying to the dynamically added links?

Comment: Are you adding a li inside another li? I think the second li declaration `.html('<li>.....` should be removed, you should leave it like this `$('<li></li>')
                    .html('<a href="'+url+ '" rel="external" data-transition="slide">'+ title +'</a>')` then refresh to see the rendering result

Comment: I see you have no class associated with the anchors..  Did you write up the CSS for the elements itself ??

Comment: @Sushanth-- Those classes should be added by JQM automatically after he calls `.trigger('create')`

Comment: What do you get from this quick test? `console.log($("[id=events-holder]").length);` Also, you should not be using `$(document).ready` in JQM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your css, but I suspect the problem is that your dynamically created `<li>`s are doubled up. You are creating an `<li>` with `$('<li></li>')` and then adding **another** `<li>` inside it in the `.html()` call.

Try removing the `<li>` tag from your `.html()` string

Comment: This is a tricky one, thanks for all your help everyone. I have deleted the second <li>, but to no avail. After having a hack around last night I realise it is not registering each line as a 'new <li>', but almost a load of text? - anyone any ideas how I can solve this? - otherwise I may have to restart with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
jQuery("#events-holder").listview('refresh');
```

and you are set.